# Google Maps - slow loading polygons

Tags: google-maps, polygon, kml

I've got a KML with 127 simple polygons in it.

If I load them all in via GGeoXml then it's lightning fast, and when you zoom in/out it redraws all the polygons (just about) instantly.

When I use either EGeoXml or CsGeoXml classes then zooming in/out becomes slow (about 4-6 seconds) as it redraws the polygons 20-30 or so at a time.

I need to put custom info windows onto each marker so GGeoXML doesn't really cut it for me.

Does GGeoXML load polygons in differently to the above classes somehow? Or does EGeoXml/CsGeoXml load/attach something that GGeoXml doesn't, causing them to go much slower?

I've also tried taking the shapes from a KML file, putting them into a JSON file and parsing that - same problem.

Any thoughts/suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In some circumstances, the GGeoXml server will choose to render polygons to tile images on the server and serve them as a tile layer to the client. That's not possible for client side extensions.

If you just want custom info windows on the markers, then you could put your markers in one KML file and your polygons in another. Render the polygons with GGeoXml and the markers with a client side extension.